# AJAX-generated <tr> becomes just the text content in firefox/chrome

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom, google-chrome

First, I request some HTML via AJAX.
Example response:

```
<tr class="recordRow">
  <td class="first recordType" id="recordType">holder</td>
  <td class="recordAmount" id="recordAmount">holder</td>
  <td class="recordDescription" id="recordDescription">holder</td>
  <td class="last recordDate" id="recordDate">holder</td>
</tr>
```

And I'm trying to make a DOM Object.

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.innerHTML = templateListItem;
alert(d.innerHTML);
alert(d.firstChild);
```

I thought this should add the row to the `<div>`, but I only get the text. When I append the response to an element, I only get the text content, e.g `holder holder holder holder`.

Why does the HTML seem to get squashed in firefox and chrome?

Added:
If example response are like:

```
<tr><td><span>something here..</span></td></tr>
```

It will alert "HTMLSpanElement"  in firefox. All tags like tr/td/ are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to insert a `<tr>` into a `<div>`, it is possible that the browser will not render this properly as it is illegal HTML.
Try placing your `<tr>` into a `<table>` element or a `<tbody>` element nested inside of a `<table>` element.

Comment: That's helpful!But how can i just create the HTMLElement,no matter what tag it is?

Comment: @NStal: Try this. This is probably the most likely cause.

Comment: The `<span>` tag is valid under a `<div>`, this is probably why it appears in the alert.From the details of your question, you mention that you want to add rows to the div using the JavaScript. Semantically, this implies you should probably replace the `<div>` tag with a `<table>` tag, as this is probably better markup for what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: In fact,I just want what ever single tag I get from the server, I was able to covert it into a HTML node.Now I just trial and error,if I get and Object text,I try to use another tag to wrap it.It works, but silly. Is there any better solution?

Comment: The minimum requirement to solve the issue of the browser not rendering your HTML nodes is simple. You should conform to the standards of HTML by correctly nesting your HTMLElements. If this requires you to wrap the response in an appropriate tag, this is a good solution.

Comment: Thanks everybody,I think your helps is enough for me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dragging that response from a server somewhere, it will just be text, as you've found out. If you can, you could change the AJAX code to return JSON, decode that, and turn it into an object.

In relation to the tags being removed, I read somewhere about browsers doing that, but it's very likely to be wrong; AJAX would fail miserably in that case.

Comment: Can it explain,why only tr failed.But still work will for almost all the other tags?

Comment: You're saying all the other tags except the `tr` are DOM elements? If so, that's strange. Try wrapping the AJAX response in a `div`, for example, then see if you can grab the `tr` inside that?

Comment: @JamWaffles it is not strange. How you want to append tr into div? good luck :)

Comment: DIV is OK,but content is gone.It becomes"<div>holder holder holder holder</div>"

Answer (score 0):

If your XHR instance is `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()`, Be sure to use `xhr.responseXML` rather than `xhr.responseText`.